# html2canvas for html page with multiple images from same source

Tags: html2canvas

I have multiple images in an html page.I want to use html2canvas to convert the page to image.The images are local and from same source.It always keep on showing the error msg       **" Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data."**

The same code will work for one image or multiple copy of same image.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="language" content="de">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var target = $('#mainDiv');
        html2canvas(target, {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
            var data = canvas.toDataURL();
            var img = document.getElementById('img1');
            img.src = data;
            }
        });
        });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mainDiv">
    <div id="div1" ><p>paragraph 1  paragraph 1  paragraph 1  paragraph 1  paragraph 1  paragraph 1  paragraph 1  paragraph 1  </p></div>
    <div id="div2" ><p>paragraph2 paragraph2 paragraph2 paragraph2 paragraph2 paragraph2 paragraph2 paragraph2 </p></div>
    <img src="images/01.jpg" >
      <img src="images/02.jpg" >
      <img src="images/03.jpg" >
      <img src="images/04.jpg" >
    </div>
  <img id="img1"></img>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am not sure what does the error message mean.Also if somebody can tell me how do i make this work with multiple images, it will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

just remove what you dont need. ie, i have Div1,Div2 etc

```
      function PrintChartCanvas(divId) {
            //div canvas
            var divObj = html2canvas($('#div' + divId));
            var divQueu = divObj.parse();
            var divCanvas = divObj.render(divQueu);
            divImg = divCanvas.toDataURL();

            return divImg;
        }
```

document.getElementById("img1").src = PrintChartCanvas(3);

This should work